# Smartgit: Can't stash

Tags: smartgit

Im having a problem in stashing my current tree, I selected all the files to be stash and it took around 5mins then it gives me an error message(see the image below).

When I tried to click the exit process, it will abort the stashing but if I clicked the wait. It will pop-up again the image below.

I tried to change my current branch to another branch, same result

Question: Has anyone experienced this issue? How can I fix this?

Additional information that might help: Programming language we are using is Laravel / Jquery and Vue js

[image]

Comment: Do you by chance use docker sharing disk C? If yes, try shutting it down.

Answer (score 0):

I think it is better to use git in command so at first check your status with command line

```
$ git status
```

After that

```
$ git stash
```